# GoogleApiClient for multiple Api's

Tags: location-services, android-googleapiclient

I am using GooglePlayServices for my android application . I will be using Google+ Api & LocationServices Api. So from Google's documentation , I build the **GoogleApiClient** with addApi(**Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API**), addApi(**LocationServices.API**). Every time user launches the application , I use Google+ api , but I use the LocationServices in rare cases (once in 100 launches). So what is the best way to implement.

Creating a single GoogleApiClient by adding two Api's ? or
Creating two GoogleApiClient's individually for those two api's?

Comment: I have same problem, you already know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

add More Api if needed

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                // Add more APIs, as needed
                .build();
```